# How to run a php CLI script from a website

Tags: php, html, exec, command-line-interface, execute

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run a PHP CLI script from a webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969250/run-a-php-cli-script-from-a-webpage)

I have a problem in here.. And it's about how to run a php cli script from a webpage.. 
Note that I'm using a localhost and the safemode is off..

I already tried exec() , system() and many others..
Here is an example of what I want to do:

The website contains:

```
<?php
//blabla
$command = "/usr/bin/php test.php";
exec($command);
//blabla
?>
```

and to check that the script was successfully run, the script "test.php" contains:

```
<?php
$file = "/home/Me/Desktop/cccc.txt";
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'aaaaa');
fclose($fp);
?>
```

executing that script from the command line is OK, but when I execute it from the website it doesn't work
 any ideas?

Comment: Does the webserver have permissions to write to the Desktop folder? As when you run the script from the webpage it is being executed as the webserver's user, and when doing directly from command line its doing it as whatever user you are signed in as

Comment: @Matt I read that but It doesn't help.. So I decided to post a question to get direct answers..

Comment: @PatrickEvans  I don't know exactly if it has the permission or not but I tried in many other folders..
and I even tried running other scripts that contains pcntl_fork() and watched the processes in the system..
Because that's what I want to do next :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with easier command like exec("dir").

If it works then try whoiam() and look for permissions.

Comment: This code works perfectly: exec('ls', $out);
print_r($out);

I don't know what I'll do now :/

Comment: and executing: echo exec(whoami);  returns: www-data

Comment: write perms prob then, be sure that www-data can write on the dir.

Comment: No it can't..
That was the problem.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the command-line command where `test.php` is; the "working directory" will almost certainly **not** be the location of the PHP files.

Try `$command = '/usr/bin/php ' . dirname(__FILE__) . 'test.php';`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the website user (typically apache) has permissions to execute this script.

Comment: and how could I do that?
and thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: It would also need permissions to write to `cccc.txt` in that directory

Comment: @ExplosionPills     I think it has the permission to do it..   any ways.. that was an example because if this script worked I'll use the basics for another one..